# Finding conjunctive normal form of a Boolean polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have to find the conjunctive normal form of the following Boolean Polynomial :

$(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1x_2+x_1'x_3)'$

I simplified this polynomial to get $x_1x_2'+x_1x_2x_3'$ for which i then formed the truth table and got the conjunctive normal form to be,

$(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1+x_2+x_3')(x_1+x_2'+x_3)(x_1+x_2'+x_3')(x_1'+x_2'+x_3')$

I just want to make sure that i am doing these problems correctly,so could someone please check my answer.

Comment: Your CNF looks correct to me. I haven't generated the truth table myself to check all the cases, but the ones you picked are all maxterms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two of the eight possible cases, the original expression and your solution are different:

For $x_1' x_2 x_3'$, the original results in *true* while your solution yields *false*.

For $x_1 x_2 x_3'$ you are getting *true* instead of *false*.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28X1%20or%20X2%20or%20X3%29%20and%20not%20%28X1%20and%20X2%20or%20%28not%20X1%29and%20X3%29) gives you a rather compact `CNF`:

$$(x_1' + x_2')(x_1 + x_2)(x_1 + x_3')$$

This minimized *product-of-sums* is not unique. An equivalent solution would be:

$$(x_1' + x_2')(x_1 + x_2)(x_2' + x_3')$$

**Hint:** 
To compare two expressions you can enter them in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) separated by comma. This allows for a direct comparison of the truth tables. Another option would be to write an *xor* of the two expressions and look for lines with *true* (indicating different expressions).